# Local Linux user that automatically executes a command thyat can't be turned off

Tags: linux, bash

I've spent last few hours looking for a solution for my problem which is:

I have my home server set up next to me with a small monitor attached to it. What i want to do is i want to create an additional user called "monitor" that executes command "nethogs eth1" straight after it has been logged one locally on the machine, and does not allow to turn off the script.

Basically i want nethogs running 24/7 on my monitor, without way to turn it off.
Please help me if you know the solution.

Comment: *I've spent last few hours looking* - then you must have found a lot - what was wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing helpful, most of the tutorials covered SSH concole, while i need a setting, that will do it on local shell.

Comment: So basically you will make fun out of me, but you won't actually help. Kind.

Comment: "can't be turned off" is going to be a tough one unless you're including the option of removing the mouse and keyboard from the machine.  (Such as a kiosk display.)

Comment: This would be a better question for superuser.com since it does not concern programming.

Comment: Basically the keyboard and the mouse are unplugged, but it is not a big deal ti plug it back. I just want to block CTRL + c shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo adduser monitor
echo "sudo -u monitor nethogs eth1" >> /etc/rc.local
```

Each time your machine boots, it will execute `nethogs eth1` as user `monitor`, and only `root` or `monitor` itself can stop that command.